# Subtracting matrix with different dimension

Tags: r

I have a matix `B` with 100 rows and 3 columns, and a matrix `C` with 100 rows and 1 column. I want to create a matrix `A` with 100 rows and 3 columns like this

```
A <- B - C
```

First row in the new matrix `A`:

```
A[1,1] <- B[1,1]-C[1,1]
```

and

```
A[1,2] <- B[1,2]-C[1,1]
```

and

```
A[1,3] <- B[1,3]-C[1,1]
```

I get the following error message when I run this code:

> Error in B - C : non-conformable arrays

Comment: A <- B - as.numeric(C)

Comment: That also worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

apply to the rescue

```
set.seed(123)
B <- matrix(sample(1:30), ncol = 3)
C <- matrix(sample(1:10), ncol = 1)
A <- apply(B, 2, `-`, C)
A
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]   -1   10    9
# [2,]   14   21   -2
# [3,]    6   16    0
# [4,]   16   21    9
# [5,]   24   25   27
# [6,]   -1   11    5
# [7,]    9    0   -1
# [8,]   14   -6    9
# [9,]   22   10   13
#[10,]    8    9    3
```

Answer (score 0):

We can coerce the 'C' to a `vector and then do the subtraction

```
A <- B - c(C)
A
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]   -1   10    9
# [2,]   14   21   -2
# [3,]    6   16    0
# [4,]   16   21    9
# [5,]   24   25   27
# [6,]   -1   11    5
# [7,]    9    0   -1
# [8,]   14   -6    9
# [9,]   22   10   13
#[10,]    8    9    3
```

Or with `as.vector`

```
A <- B - as.vector(C)
```

#### data

```
set.seed(123)
B <- matrix(sample(1:30), ncol = 3)
C <- matrix(sample(1:10), ncol = 1)
```